# What’s the origin of the phrase “pay attention”? Did one have to pay monies for this historically?

Tags: phrase-origin

Does the phrase “pay attention” imply there used to be a fee for performing said action? If so, how would this be collected? In other words is “paying attention” objectively observable and therefore taxable? I suspect this phrase dates backs to Stalinist Russia, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 5):

No, it is nothing to do with paying a fee.

Note first that the Corpus of Historical American English shows instances from 1822, so it is nothing to do with Stalinist Russia.

Secondly, the oldest meaning of "pay" given in the OED is "To appease, pacify; to satisfy, content, gratify; to be acceptable to". This is marked as "obsolete", and the latest example given is around 1500. But it indicates that the idea of exchange (let alone money) was not always present when the word first entered English. (senses involving payment are around from the beginning as well, but not exclusively)

The relevant meaning here is the OED's 14a:

> To give, render (something which is due to or rightfully claimed by the recipient, as homage, allegiance, etc.); to discharge, perform (a promise or vow). Usually with *to* or double object.

from 1340; and 14 b:

> With the sense of debt, obligation, etc., weakened or lost: to render, bestow, or give (attention, heed, a compliment, etc.). Usually with *to* or double object.

from 1600.

So the meaning goes from "give what is due" to "give what is rightly claimed" to "give the kind of thing that is deserved".   None of these senses have the idea of exchange in them.